# Table primeng TotalRecords Jasmine Karma Angular error TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'totalRecords')

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner, primeng

I need to test this component that creates rows of the tablets using primeng, I have a problem to reach the totalRecords, since I get undefined value this is the component

mark with a /** ! **/

where do i get the errors

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { ConfirmationService, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

/** Services */
import { CuentaConceptoCargoService } from '../../../services/cuenta-concepto-cargo.service';
import { Helpers } from 'src/app/shared/helpers/helpers';
import { msgServiceError, msgServiceSuccess, msgServiceWarn } from 'src/app/shared/helpers/utils-message-services';

/** Interfaces */
import { Concepto } from 'src/app/modules/configuration/sub-modules/nomina/formulacion/conceptos/interfaces/concepto.interfaces';
import { CuentaConceptoCargo } from '../../../interfaces/cuenta-concepto-cargo.interfaces';
import { Cargo } from '../../../../../nomina/generacion/cargo/interfaces/cargo.interfaces';
import { TipoCosto } from '../../../../tipo-costo/interfaces/tipo-costo.interfaces';
import { SortEventOrder, TableHead } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/tableHead.interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-add-edit-cargo',
  templateUrl: './modal-add-edit-cargo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-add-edit-cargo.component.scss'],
  providers: [ MessageService, ConfirmationService ]
})
export class ModalAddEditCargoComponent implements OnInit {

  // Objeto seleccionado para enviar IdEmpresa, IdNomina e Idconcepto
  @Input() conceptoSelect!: Concepto| undefined;

  // Objeto para cuentas cargos
  cuentasCargos: CuentaConceptoCargo[] = [];

  // Titulo del modal
  @Input() titleModal!: string;

  // Variable para abrir modal Cuentas Cargos
  @Input() modalCuentaCargo: boolean = false;

  /***********************************************************
   * Objetos de tablas tipos Cuentas Cargos                  *
   ***********************************************************/
  
  // Objeto para la lista de cargos segun la empresa 
  @Input() cargos: Cargo[] = [];

  // Objetos para lista de tipo de costos
  @Input() tiposCostos: TipoCosto[] = [];

  /**************************
   * Fin Objetos de tablas  *
   **************************/

  // Formulario reactivo
  form!: FormGroup;

  // Columnas de la table
  columns: TableHead[] = [];

  // Cantidad de registros por página
  rows: number = 10;

  // Variable para comprobar si existen cambios
  isChangesTable: boolean = false;

  // Emisión de eventos (cerrar modal)
  @Output() onCloseModalCuentaCargo = new EventEmitter();

  // Emisión de eventos (loadData)
  @Output() onLoadDataCuentaCargo   = new EventEmitter();

  // Obtener el elemento de la tabla mediante el DOM
  @ViewChild('dt') table!: Table;

  /**
   * Retorna las cargos contables en un array
   * @Returns FormArray
   */
  get cargosContableFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get("cargosContables") as FormArray;
  }

  /**
   * Método set por el decorador Input() para detectar cambios en la variable
   */
  @Input()
  set cuentasCargosInput(data: CuentaConceptoCargo[]) {
    this.cuentasCargos = data;
    if ( this.cuentasCargos.length > 0 ) {
      this.cuentasCargos.forEach((data, index) => {
        /** !! in this part the method of this.table.totalRecords is called for the first time **/
        this.addControls();
        this.cargosContableFormArray.controls[index].setValue(data);
        /** Obtener el formGroup de la tabla*/
        const formGroupData = this.cargosContableFormArray.controls[index] as FormGroup;
        /** Deshabilitar campos cuando el estado es para actualizar */
        if ( data.estatus === 'UPDATE' ) {
          formGroupData.controls['idCargo'].disable();
          formGroupData.controls['tipcos'].disable();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  constructor(private cargoService: CuentaConceptoCargoService,
              private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
              private messageService: MessageService,
              private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
              private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
              private helpers: Helpers,
              private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      cargosContables: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  /**
   * Método de Angular para comprobar expresiones y deteccion de cambios en la vista antes cambiar valores
   */
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    // Eliminar errores de [ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError]
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns = [
      { field: 'idCargo',  header: 'Cargos'               },
      { field: 'tipcos',   header: 'Tipo de costo'        },
      { field: 'ctacon',   header: 'Cuenta'               },
      { field: 'posrel',   header: 'Posiciones relativas' }
    ];
  }
  
  /**
   * Agregar una nueva fila vacia con valores por defecto en la tabla prime ng
   */
  addNewRow() {
    /** Variable para mostrar al usuario que hay cambios */
    this.isChangesTable = true;
    // Crear un nuevo form control en el array
    const newDataRow = this.newArrayControl();
    // Deshabilitar campo tipo costo
    newDataRow.controls['tipcos'].disable();
    // Redondear el número con el fin de posicionar la página correspondiente cuando se agrega una fila
    this.table.first = Math.floor(this.table.value.length / this.rows) * this.rows;
    // Actualizar el total de los registros de la tabla con la nueva fila agregada.
    this.table.totalRecords = this.table.value.length + 1;
    // Agregar un nuevo objeto a los valores de la tabla
    this.table.value.push(newDataRow);
    // Iniciar la edición para agregar el registro ( Se arma un nuevo objeto [controls] para el dataKey de la tabla de primeNg )
    this.table.initRowEdit({ ...newDataRow.value, controls: { idTableTemporal: { value: newDataRow.value.idTableTemporal } }});
    // Reiniciar la cantidad de rows que pueden ver en la tabla cuando se crea una nueva fila
    this.table._rows = this.rows;
  }

  /**
   * Añadir el control al formulario
   */
  addControls(): void {
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();
    this.cargosContableFormArray.push(this.newArrayControl());
    // Actualizar el total de los registros de la tabla
    /** !! the next part is where you can't locate the totalRecords **/
    this.table.totalRecords = this.cargosContableFormArray.length;
  }

  /**
   * Establecer un nuevo array en el formulario con las validaciones necesarias
   * @returns FormGroup
   */
  newArrayControl(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      // Colocar un id temporal en el registro para el [dataKey] de la tabla
      idTableTemporal: new FormControl(this.getIdTemporalMax()),
      // Valores para crear concepto por empresa, nomina y concepto
      idEmpresa:    new FormControl(this.conceptoSelect?.idEmpresa),
      idNomina:     new FormControl(this.conceptoSelect?.idNomina),
      idConcepto:   new FormControl(this.conceptoSelect?.id),
      // Data necesaria para crear
      idCargo:      new FormControl(null, [ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10) ]),
      tipcos:       new FormControl(null, [ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(1)  ]),
      ctacon:       new FormControl(null, [ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(36) ]), 
      posrel:       new FormControl(null, [ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(36) ]), 
      // Estatus por defecto para crear 
      estatus:      new FormControl('CREATE')
    });
  }

  /**
   * Obtener el valor máximo del arreglo y retornar el siguiente valor.
   * @returns number
   */
  getIdTemporalMax(): number {
    return this.cargosContableFormArray.value.length == 0 ? 0 : this.cargosContableFormArray.controls.length;
  }

  /**
   * Habilitar y resetear campo tipo costo
   * @param index: number: indice del formGroup
   * @returns void
   */
  cargoSelectChange(index: number): void {
    // Obtener el formGroup de la tabla
    const formGroupData = this.cargosContableFormArray.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    // Habilitar campo tipo de costo
    formGroupData.controls['tipcos'].reset();
    formGroupData.controls['tipcos'].enable();
  }

  /**
   * Validar cargo y tipo de costo duplicado
   * @param index: number: indice del formGroup
   */
  validateCargoTipoCosto(index: number): void {
    // Obtener el formGroup de la tabla
    const formGroupData = this.cargosContableFormArray.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    const idCargo = formGroupData.controls['idCargo'].value;
    const tipcos = formGroupData.controls['tipcos'].value;
    /** Obtener la data actual de la tabla */
    let formArrayData: CuentaConceptoCargo[] = this.form.getRawValue().cargosContables;
    /** Filtramos los registros diferente al estatus 'DELETE' y el registro que se quiere crear */
    formArrayData = formArrayData.filter(data => data.estatus !== 'DELETE' && data.idTableTemporal !== index);
    /** Validar que el campo idCargo y tipo de costo no esten duplicados */
    return formArrayData.findIndex(val => Number(val.idCargo) === Number(idCargo) && Number(val.tipcos) === Number(tipcos)) > -1 ? 
                                  this.errorDuplicated(true, index) : 
                                  this.errorDuplicated(false, index);
  }

  /**
   * Colocar errores en la vista si esta duplicado
   * @param duplicated: boolean, validar si esta duplicado o no
   * @param index: indice del array del formGroup
   */
  errorDuplicated(duplicated: boolean, index: number): void {
    // Obtener el formGroup de la tabla
    const formGroupData = this.cargosContableFormArray.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    if (duplicated) {
      formGroupData.controls['idCargo'].setErrors( {'duplicated': true });
      formGroupData.controls['tipcos'].setErrors( {'duplicated': true });
      return;
    }
    formGroupData.controls['idCargo'].setErrors(null);
    formGroupData.controls['tipcos'].setErrors(null);
  }

  /**
   * Metodo para guardar y actualizar registros
   * @returns void
   */
  save(): void {
    /** Variable para obtener la excepción */
    let BreakException = {};
    /** Obtener el formArray de la tabla */
    const formArrayData = this.form.controls.cargosContables as FormArray;
    /** Obtener el formGroup de la tabla */
    const formGroupData = formArrayData.controls as FormGroup[];
    /** Validar todos los controles del formulario */
    try {
      formGroupData.forEach(element => {
        if (element.invalid) {
          this.form.markAllAsTouched();
          throw BreakException;
        }
      });
    } catch (err: any) {
      if (err !== BreakException) throw err;
      /** Retornamos del método Save */
      return;
    }
    /** Validar que se haya seleccionado un concepto */
    if (!this.conceptoSelect) {
      this.messageService.add(msgServiceError('Debe seleccionar un concepto'));
      return;
    }
    // Obtener formulario
    let data: CuentaConceptoCargo[] = this.form.getRawValue().cargosContables;

    this.spinner.show();

    // Editar
    this.cargoService.update(this.conceptoSelect, data)
      .subscribe({
        next: (resp) => {
          this.spinner.hide();
          this.messageService.add(msgServiceSuccess(resp.message));
          this.onLoadEmit();
          return true;
        },
        error: (err) => {
          if ( err.error.message.includes('Error en solicitud.') ) {
            this.spinner.hide();
            this.messageService.add(msgServiceWarn(err.error.detail));
            return false;
          }
          this.spinner.hide();
          this.messageService.add(msgServiceError(err.error.detail, err.status, err.error.error));
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

This is my spec.ts

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { ModalAddEditCargoComponent } from './modal-add-edit-cargo.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { CuentaConceptoUnidadOrganizativaService } from '../../../services/cuenta-concepto-unidad-organizativa.service';
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { CuentaConceptoCargoService } from '../../../services/cuenta-concepto-cargo.service';
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';


describe('ModalEditComponent', () => {
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  const URL = `${environment.api}/configuraciones/nominas`;

  let service: CuentaConceptoUnidadOrganizativaService
  let serviceCargo: CuentaConceptoCargoService

  beforeEach( waitForAsync  (() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MessageService
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        TableModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ModalAddEditCargoComponent
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents()
    
    // Peticiones mock
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(CuentaConceptoUnidadOrganizativaService);
    serviceCargo = TestBed.inject(CuentaConceptoCargoService);
  }));


  it('Crear componente de Cuenta Concepto Editar', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalAddEditCargoComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Inicializar el componente Forma de Editar', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalAddEditCargoComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
   
    app.cuentasCargosInput = [
        {
            // Codigo de la Compañia
            idEmpresa:  'string',
            // Tipo de Nomina
            idNomina:   'string',
            // Codigo del Concepto
            idConcepto: 12,
            // Codigo del Cargo
            idCargo:    'string',
            // Tipo de costo, clasificacion de mano de obra
            tipcos:     'string',
            // Cuenta Contable
            ctacon:     'string',
            // Posiciones Relativas
            posrel:     'string',
            // Estado (CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE)
            estatus:    'string',
            // Id temporal para [dataKey] de tabla Cell editing
            idTableTemporal:        1,
        }
    ]

    app.cuentasCargos = app.cuentasCargosInput



    // Validamos el requiere de los campos
    
    expect(app.form.valid).toEqual(true)

    // Se valida que haya cambios en el input isEdit
      
    app.conceptoSelect = undefined

    // validamos que no exista el nivelSelect

    expect(app.conceptoSelect).toEqual(undefined);
  
  });

});
```

what I hope is that this error that I get when executing the ng test disappears[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNBqS.png)

Comment: The `ViewChild` of the `table` is not working, I am not sure why that's not working. Try doing `console.log(fixture.nativeElement);` on the failing test to see if the `table` is in the HTML or not.

Comment: @AliF50 Definitely not among HTML elements. There is a variable to make it visible but when I call it with a true value it keeps giving me the same error, I leave an image of how I am calling it and how it is represented in the template.

Comment: @AliF50 https://ibb.co/YyB68cV

Comment: I see. Maybe you're missing a directive to be added into the `declarations` array for it to take effect and display the table?